# Google map error

Tags: webmatrix-3

I am facing an error Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'Maps' does not exist in the current context
i named this file as MapAddress.cshtml and jquery file also matches which i have and i have also intalled version 2 of the ASP.NET Web HelpersLibrary. everything almost set from my side but still i am facing that error,i don't know why?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Map an Address</title>
  <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Map an Address</h1>
    <form method="post">
        <fieldset>
          <div>
            <label for="address">Address:</label>
            <input style="width: 300px" type="text" name="address" value="@Request["address"]"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Map It!" />
           </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
    @if(IsPost) {
        @Maps.GetGoogleHtml(Request.Form["address"],
            width: "400",
            height: "400")
    }
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't you need an extra <script /> tag for your maps API?

Comment: No i dont need at all, if you have any idea why i am facing this error let me know?

Comment: Maps is defined in the google map API.You definitely need to reference it in your html. ... https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial ... have you read this?

Comment: No dear i haven't read it before even heard,i am reading this, hope it will be helpful

Comment: ok. Well when you've read it, you need to get an API key, and then you will need to add `<script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY">` to your html. Good luck! :0)

Comment: I have no idea what to do now,i read that and followed all steps and i have recieved a key also but when i place that key on the place of API key it does no effect on my page or even error is still same.

Comment: OK .. how about trying this example out ... http://www.w3schools.com/googleapi/google_maps_basic.asp